# Why doesn't my urls.py work?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

```
url(r'^video/?$','stuff.abc.views.video',name="video"),
```

This doesn't work:

```
<a href="{% url video %}">Videos</a>
```

But this works:

```
<a href="/video">Videos</a>
```

the error is:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Tried ad in module stuff.abc.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'ad'
```

Comment: The rest of the file says...?

Comment: Which file? the template, or the urls.py? This is the only thing in templates.

Comment: Yeah, I gotta say the error doesn't look related to your snippet there. There is no mention of "ad" in the snippet, but your error message complains that "ad" doesn't exist. It looks like you're trying to pass something on the query string -- look into Django's docs for how to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url itself isn't breaking things, it's the `stuff.abc.views` module that has the error.

Somewhere in that module (and probably in the `video` view function), you are attempting to access an attribute called `ad` that doesn't exist.

The error is confusing because it says `ViewDoesNotExist`, but that's really just Django getting confused because it expects to be catching an `attribute error` for a different reason right there.